# How to query or report on Duplicates Match

Tags: apex, soql, reporting, duplicate-management, matcher

I am using Duplicate Management; Matching Rules; Duplicate Rules from Salesforce, standard out of the box. This helps a lot to stop the bleeding and limit the manual duplicate generation. I notice that when I open an account, I have a message that detects potential duplicate on Account.

[image]

Is it possible to query, or report, to identify ALL potential duplicate of my organisation. I want to do this in order to identify merge candidates.

The related Q/A from the previous post ["Duplicate Matching Rules via rest API"](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66050/duplicate-matching-rules-via-rest-api/66926#66926) might give some start of solution

Answer (score 1):

You need to build  [Custom Report Types for Duplicate Record Reports](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=duplicate_management_custom_report_types.htm&language=en_US&type=0).

> Use the Report action to fine-tune your duplicate rules. Duplicate record reports let you analyze the quality of your data and see how well your duplicate rules are working. Use the examples we provide to set up the appropriate custom report types.

The following records appear in these reports.

- Records identified as duplicates by duplicate rules that include the report action, where the user bypassed the duplicate alert and saved the records.
- Records that were manually added to the Duplicate Record Set object.

Comment: Hi Santanu, thank you, but it does not meet my need, I experimented with the report action. It only includes alerts generated on update or insert after the rule was set. I am looking for a way to use the standard matching rules, without forcing insertions, or updates. What you are suggesting is fine, but it will only include newly reported potential duplicates.

Comment: Then you could look for this ans: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/175645/how-do-i-find-duplicates-using-ootb-duplicate-management-without-performing-a-dm/175649#175649