# Report: Leads with same name and company

Tags: reporting, duplicate-management

What SOSQL query can list Lead Names where the Name and Company have a duplicate. (to de-dupe Leads for the same person in the same company).

This query won't execute as Count doesn't seem to support fields as well:

SELECT
    name, company, COUNT(*)
FROM
    lead
GROUP BY
    name, company
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1

Comment: you want `COUNT(Id)`

Comment: Oh right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using:

```
SELECT Name, Company, COUNT(Id) FROM Lead GROUP BY Name, Company HAVING COUNT(Id) > 1
```

Comment: Thank You. I added (Id) and it works.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted so as to benefit the Community.  I'm glad the solution was simple.

Answer (score 0):

If you use duplicate rules you could build a standard report with the [Duplicate Record Set](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=duplicate_management_duplicate_record_sets.htm&type=5) Object.

Comment: See also here on how to create a report type and report to it https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=duplicate_management_custom_report_types.htm&type=5