# Cannot insert Contact with REST API if a Lead with the same e-mail address exists

Tags: rest-api, rest, contact, leads

I noticed in the UI that when I try to insert a contact with an e-mail address that a lead already has, I get a warning (before I click save and insert the contact) saying that this is a possible duplicate. However, I am still able to save the contact ignoring the warning. This is something that I often want to happen. But I can't seem to find anything in the docs that offers a way to force the operation when I'm inserting the same contact with the REST API. What seems to be a warning in the UI is an error in the REST API. Is there a way (in the REST API) to ignore this error and insert the contact anyway? It certainly seems possible when done manually through the UI.

Comment: As of now it seems you cannot bypass this while using standard REST APIs. There's an [**idea**](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lEL5QAM) to introduce the [DuplicateRuleHeader](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_header_duplicateruleheader.htm) as available in SOAP API. Take a look on this [**question**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66050/duplicate-matching-rules-via-rest-api), if that provides some direction using custom REST API implementation

Comment: So basically, I have to either use the SOAP API or rewrite my code in Apex that I then make externally callable over HTTP (is this what you mean by custom REST API implementation)?

Comment: That's correct. If you have a way to actually call it using SOAP API, will recommend that, because say once in future if the feature is delivered in REST API, your code just becomes obsolete.

Comment: Well, thanks for pointing me to the other question. At least I'm not clueless now :) I'm not entirely sure if my question qualifies as a duplicate though

Comment: I am not sure either :). The answer on the question provides an approach but as for your question, the issue still exists that you cannot bypass duplicate rules using REST API. Will leave it for the forum to decide :)

Comment: Can you edit your post to clarify if you have active duplicate management rules?  If so, on which objects and are you using custom or standard matching rules?

Comment: @DavidCheng I just looked at that and it turns out the standard matching rules seem to be causing this. I disabled them for now, to see if that solves the problem. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: I ran into this issue as well. Are these rules documented or exposed anywhere?