# DUPLICATES_DETECTED via Rest API

Tags: rest-api

Currently when trying to create an Account via the Rest API I get this message:

`[{"message":"Use one of these records?","errorCode":"DUPLICATES_DETECTED","fields":[]}]`

Is there a way I can send DUPLICATE_DETECTION_MATCH_INVOCATION_DETAILS via the rest API when a Duplicate is detected?
It would be great to know the SalesForce IDs of the detected Duplicates.

Does this require a custom trigger?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the REST API version missed this important header at this point. There is an idea that you can upvote [here](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lEL5QAM)

So alternatives are

- Build your own apex class that does DML, this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66050/duplicate-matching-rules-via-rest-api/66926#66926) has some important details on how you can achieve this.
- Use [SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_header_duplicateruleheader.htm), sounds backward in 2020 to do this.