# Insert Duplicate Leads via Salesforce API

Tags: leads

While creating leads in salesforce through the Lead API (/services/data/v39.0/sobjects/Lead), I am getting BadRequest response with the message:

`[{"message":"Use one of these records?","errorCode":"DUPLICATES_DETECTED","fields":[]}]`

The Allow duplicate leads is checked in the portal settings.
When I try to create the same lead from the Portal, it shows me the warning and allows me to submit the lead which i understand is the expected behavior.

My question is: How do i submit the duplicate leads using the API? Is there a way i can specify to forcibly create the leads like i do from the UI?

Comment: Please check this post https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66050/duplicate-matching-rules-via-rest-api. Might be helpful

Comment: change the duplicate matching rules to be cognizant of the API user (assuming you have a dedicated set of users allowed to use the API)